# комбинации элементов словаря с вложенными массивами

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

есть словарь с вложенными массивами

```
dics = {"i1": 1,
        "l2": [4, 5, 6, 7],
        "i3": 8,
        "l4": [9, 10],
        "l5": [11, 12]}
```

как найти комбинации элементов словаря но так что б в каждой комбинации было не больше одного элемента из каждого вложенного массива ?

Comment: Декартово произведение. `itertools.product`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.